# What type should my comparator be

Tags: java, comparator

That's the `List` I would like to compare according to the integer in the entry's value

```
List<Map.Entry<OfficerRank, Integer>> lst = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<OfficerRank, Integer>>();
lst.addAll(mp.entrySet());
Collections.sort(lst,new CompareRank<Map.Entry<OfficerRank, Integer>>());
```

And that's my comparator code:

```
public class CompareRank<Map.Entry<OfficerRank,Integer>> implements Comparator<Map.Entry<OfficerRank, Integer>>{
  @Override
  public int compare(Map.Entry<OfficerRank,Integer> arg0, Map.Entry<OfficerRank,Integer> arg1) {
    int val1 = arg0.getValue();
    int val2 = arg1.getValue();
    return Integer.compare(val2,val1);
  }
```

My problem is that I can't use `Map.Entry<OfficerRank,Integer>` as the type according to Eclipse

Thank you

Comment: Please show the complete error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have it now, the type-parameters of `CompareRank` are aliases, not actual types.

You don't have to define type-parameters for your `CompareRank` class, just point out which are the actual types that the `Comparator` has to deal with:

```
import static java.util.Map.Entry;

public class CompareRank implements Comparator<Entry<OfficerRank, Integer>>{
  @Override
  public int compare(Entry<OfficerRank,Integer> arg0, Entry<OfficerRank,Integer> arg1) {
    int val1 = arg0.getValue();
    int val2 = arg1.getValue();
    return Integer.compare(val2,val1);
}
```

Then, you should instantiate it like this:

```
Collections.sort(lst, new CompareRank());
```

Answer (score 0):

please use likewise:

```
public class CompareRank implements Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Entry<Integer, Integer> o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here, For easiness i have taken `Entry<Integer, Integer>,`

but you can go on with `Entry<YOURCLASSTYPE, Integer>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using wrongly Map.Entry here. If you want to use it as a tuple, probably is better to define a helper "tuple" class:

```
public class Tuple<T1,T2> {
   // etc...
}
```

and instantiate it as a:

```
Tuple<OfficeRank,Integer> entry = ...
```

Or, even better, a class that encapsulates both OfficeRank and Integer, with some semantic meaning within the domain of your problem.

```
public class OfficeRankValue {
    Integer whateverTheIntegerIs;
    OfficeRank officeRank;
}
```